# No kernel message on jupyterlab and jupyter notebook

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I have been using jupyter applications such as `jupyter-lab` and the `jupyter-notebook` for quite some time without any issues, but today I noticed a kernel problem while launching `jupyter-lab` from the command line or via the `anaconda-navigator` (I have installed [Anaconda with Python3.7 for Linux](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/)).

When I try to launch `jupyter-lab` via the command line, I get the following error messages (which also pop-up if I try to call `jupyter-lab` via anaconda navigator:

```
[I 16:37:07.486 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 16:37:07.486 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /home/user/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab
[W 16:37:07.487 LabApp] JupyterLab server extension not enabled, manually loading...
[I 16:37:07.488 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 16:37:07.488 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /home/user/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab
[I 16:37:07.489 LabApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/user
[I 16:37:07.489 LabApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 16:37:07.489 LabApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=b5912dbe9af5317da84389aaa05b8e96abd7e6402ec508ad
[I 16:37:07.489 LabApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 16:37:07.503 LabApp] 

To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
file:///run/user/17930/jupyter/nbserver-17066-open.html
Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
http://localhost:8888/?token=b5912dbe9af5317da84389aaa05b8e96abd7e6402ec508ad
[I 16:37:09.485 LabApp] Node v8.15.0

[I 16:37:09.620 LabApp] Build is up to date
[I 16:37:10.026 LabApp] Kernel started: 7cc817c2-a48b-40bf-9721-c3401175a0e9
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in 
from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/__init__.py", line 2, in 
from .connect import *
File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/connect.py", line 13, in 
from IPython.core.profiledir import ProfileDir
File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 54, in 
from .core.application import Application
File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 23, in 
from traitlets.config.application import Application, catch_config_error
File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/__init__.py", line 6, in 
from .application import *
File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 19, in 
from traitlets.config.configurable import Configurable, SingletonConfigurable
File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/configurable.py", line 12, in 
from .loader import Config, LazyConfigValue, _is_section_key
File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/loader.py", line 49, in 
class ArgumentParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
AttributeError: module 'argparse' has no attribute 'ArgumentParser'
```

(then the computer tries to restart the kernel five times. After failing all five attempts to restart the kernel, the computer gives up and I see a `No kernel` on `jupyter-lab`)

I am having a hard-time finding what the cause of the error can be because, as far as I recall, I did not make any change in any Python installation interpreter or anything like that. Also, other applications which were also installed via Anaconda, such as `Spyder`, are working normally.

The only thing that I recall that I changed is that I added a manual proxy configuration for `Firefox`, which has always been my default browser. Nevertheless, I have set back the option to `No proxy` on `Firefox` and it does not work. Other than that, I get the very same problem if I set the default browser to `google chrome`.

Does anyone